# Trusteer Rapport "security software" says my computer is infected

Tags: windows, security, malware

I'm sure I'm not the first person to come across this, but here in the UK it seems every major bank (e.g. **HSBC**, **NatWest**, etc.) are getting their customers to install **Trusteer's [Rapport software](http://www.trusteer.com/product/trusteer-rapport)** before they do any sort of online banking. The idea being that this software protects their customer's credentials when logging on to their banking service.

This is all well and good, but I got tired of having it installed on my system, and during a tidy-up I decided to uninstall it... Except I got the following message telling me my computer was infected with malicious software:

[image]

Clicking on the "more info" link takes you here: 
http://www.trusteer.com/infected

There is no further information on what this supposed threat is, or why this threat would no longer be "quarantined" if I uninstalled Rapport, or even why malware scanners would not find it.

The whole thing smacks of **scareware**. Has anyone had any experiences with this software or this company? My instinct is to get rid of anything that attempts such tactics. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Rapport is described as "snake oil" here: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/12/snake-oil-legitimate-vendors-s.html Hmm!

Comment: Well here's an update: I tried to uninstall their software again, just now, and I DIDN'T get the above message. They may have been telling the truth the first time around (I've since tidyied up my computer more since then) or they fixed their software in the meantime. That's somewhat good then, but it's still very bad that they don't inform the user as to WHAT malicious software they've found on your machine, only that you won't be protected if you remove their software. That, to me, IS scareware tactics, even if it's a milder version of what I originally thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest test to do would be to have a [VM](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install this software there.

If you then try and un-install on the VM and it gives you the same message then chances are (unless of course you manage to get infected in 5 minutes) this is the default message that it gives.

Answer (score 0):

Rapport has completely sabotaged my computer.  Immediately after downloading Rapport my computer crashed (over the Xmas holiday).  I cant get into anything, it has taken days and nights to get the simplest actions done to run diagnostic tests and the diagnostic results have been very serious.  The computer is only about 2.5 years old and it seriously looks like I will have to get a new one.  Although most of the stuff on the computer was copied onto CDs there are hundreds of more recent files which have not. A simple automatic process is taking hours and we are going round in circles trying to get it sorted.  We had McAfee Security system and there were no viruses on the computer at the time.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Answer (score -2):

This message appears only if Rapport has identified malicious software on your computer.
Rapport does not remove malicious software as this can cause errors, file corruption or simply leave the door open for the Malware to install itself again.

Thus, Rapport blocks the Malware from accessing sensitive information.
Removing Rapport enables the Malware to operate normally again.

If you would like to know exactly what Rapport has identified and why this message has appeared, please contact us at support@trusteer.com and provide your Rapport ID, which can be found under "More settings" in the Rapport console. The Rapport console can be opened through the start menu.

Best Regards,

Trusteer Support Team

Comment: I have done this, but apparently your software is having difficulty sending the required information to you. I find it unacceptable to say things like, "If you remove Trusteer Rapport, this malicious software will become active once again", but to not provide any additional information to the user. It sounds remarkably like scareware tactics, intentionally or not.

Comment: @user4796 - I will call your software for what it is, useless, and something somebody should remove from their system.  The message clearly provide no information, which simply means, the system was never infected.

Answer (score -2):

I use Gdata anti virus which seems to work OK. I downloaded Rapport on the advice of HSBC. Immediately Gdata told me they had found malware and that I should perform a reboot CD. They told me this twice and warned that I should not do any online banking in the meantime. The strange thing is that when I check the Gdata logs, there is no record of this malware being found and they assure me that everything is running fine. Also the language used in the warning was not typical of Gdata. I also suspect scaremongering.

Comment: This does not really answer the user's question.